# App Engine Java 11 helloworld-servlet sample on a local jetty: 404 error after loading page

Tags: google-app-engine, jetty, java-11

I am trying to run on a local server the sample published by google at this page:
[helloworld-servlet](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/main/appengine-java11/helloworld-servlet)

There was no issue when I ran it a few weeks ago but now there is a  404 error after loading the (jsp) page.

As instructed in the Readme the steps to run on a local server are:

1
At \appengine-java11\appengine-simple-jetty-main  run:
mvn install

2
At \appengine-java11\helloworld-servlet  run:
mvn package

3
At \appengine-java11\appengine-simple-jetty-main  run:

mvn exec:java -Dexec.args="../helloworld-servlet/target/helloworld.war"

4
visit: http://localhost:8080/hello

It loads the page  (a jsp) with styled text but gives a 404 error in devtools:
GET http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)

I tried these but the issue persists:

1
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository

2
jar tf helloworld.war shows correct contents

3
Issue persists when sample is built & run on a different pc.

4
Upgrade of jetty to version 11 from 9 makes no difference.

JDK SE 17.0.10 is installed on both machines, previously might have been something different.

Comment: Do you have a favicon (icon)? If you don't, then the error is expected

Comment: This is a very small google sample, it doesn't contain anything apart from 2 small java files and 2 pom.xml files for 2 projects. It uses jsp for the hello page. Strange thing is it ran ok a few weeks ago.

Comment: 1) 404 means not found. 2) The error is about a missing icon 3) Since you don't have the icon (image), the error is expected. 4) If you've never had the icon, then you most likely had the error weeks back (maybe you just didn't notice it). 5) Missing favicon won't stop your app from running - see [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) of a favicon

Comment: Thanks, I guessed it was something silly: I was confusing this sample with several other hello world samples that do a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It loads the page (a jsp) with styled text but gives a 404 error in devtools: GET http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)

That's correct.  You should see:
[image]

That's all it's supposed to do.

If you're not seeing that, this was my setup:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.9+9 (build 17.0.9+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.9+9 (build 17.0.9+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.9.6
```

And my install steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples.git
cd java-docs-samples\appengine-java11\appengine-simple-jetty-main
mvn install
cd ../helloworld-servlet
mvn clean package
cd ../appengine-simple-jetty-main
mvn install
mvn exec:java -Dexec.args="../helloworld-servlet/target/helloworld.war"
```

Then navigate to:  http://localhost:8080/hello

PS: The page isn't a JSP, it's just a HttpServlet ([HelloAppEngine.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/main/appengine-java11/helloworld-servlet/src/main/java/com/example/appengine/HelloAppEngine.java))